# "Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type" error when used in sequelize getter and setter functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to locally run a solution built on NodeJS and NestJS. My major problem is whole bunch of error messages like this one...

> error TS2345: Argument of type '"totalShares"' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '"get" | "set" | "isNewRecord" | "sequelize" |
> "where" | "getDataValue" | "setDataValue" | "setAttributes" |
> "changed" | "previous" | "save" | "reload" | "validate" | "update" |
> ...  10 more ... | "hasHooks"'.
>
> 117       return this.getDataValue('totalShares') || 0;

I'm getting these errors from the model files (typescript-sequelize) wherever there is a custom getter and/or setter under the @Column decorator. So from snippets like this one

```
@Column({
    get(): number {
      return this.getDataValue('totalShares') || 0;
    },
  })
  totalShares: number;
```

Syntactically this looks fine to me. My first gut feel was that this may be caused by package versions mismatch, but after some light version checkups, it does not seem likely to me anymore.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From [what's shown in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript#accessors), it looks like getters and setters should be done outside of the decorator, so it should look like this:

```js
@Column
get totalShares(): number {
  return this.getDataValue('totalShares') || 0;
}

set totalShares(shares: number) {
  this.setDataValue('totalShares', shares);
}
```

Comment: A little bit above the place in the npmjs doc you linked to there is actually an example of this syntax with attribute options being used. Search for "Or for a more detailed column description, use an object literal" in the page and you'll see it right below. 

I will, of course, try changing the syntax to what you linked to in the meantime... Thanks.

Comment: I see that the `@Column()` can take attribute options, but I don't see anything in the documentation about accessors being set in the decorator, and from a typescript point of view, that makes sense. Decorators don't have access to the same `this` as member methods and properties do, so you can't reference `this` in a decorator.